# Netezza merge table with pipe delimited file

Tags: netezza

We are using Netezza in order to store tables. Every day, an updated version of the table will come in as a pipe delimited text file. So I know how to import the text file into Netezza but is there a way I can merge the pipe delimited file with the existing table in Netezza? The schema will always be the same and I would like to do it without having to load the pipe delimited file, doing the merge and than deleting the file that I just loaded because it is a big table so it'll take time.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create a external temp table ‘same as Target’ pointing to the file of the Day
2) do an Insert into Target select * from ExternalTempTable

Not much more to it if I understand you correctly

Comment: thanks for the response. I don't want to just append everything to the file. I want to merge them so adding new records and updating existing ones. Would I still be able to do this with an external table?

Comment: I’m trying to understand: do you wish to add the content of the table to a file, or do you want to add the content of the file to a table?

Comment: That being said: external tables behave 99% like normal tables from a sql perspective once they are created, so I’m convinced it is possible to do a ‘merge’ using that technology.

Comment: sorry, I want to add the contents of the file to a table.. also would it be worse (performance wise) to merge with an external table?

Comment: I wouldn’t worry. Reading from an external table into a TEMP table is quite fast, and once the incoming data is inside Netezza performance will be fine while you execute the sql to accomplish your ‘merge’...